# How to account for air resistance in a sphere being released against a flow or air?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, physics, classical-mechanics

The problem is as follows:

> A bob is hanging from the ceiling of a specially designed room where a
>   flow of air is being blown against. The bob is makes a $53^{\circ}$
>   angle with respect of the ground as indicated in the figure. The mass
>   of the sphere is $2\,kg$. Assume that the wire is ideal. The flow of
>   air excerts a constant force whose modulus is $4\,N$. Given these
>   conditions, find the modulus of the force in $N$ in the wire when the
>   sphere passes through its lowest point.

[image: Sketch of the problem]

The alternatives are as follows:

$\begin{array}{ll}
1.&26.9\,N\\
2.&29.6\,\frac{m}{s^2}\\
3.&27.5\,\frac{m}{s^2}\\
4.&23.3\,\frac{m}{s^2}\\
5.&21.2\,\frac{m}{s^2}\\
\end{array}$

I'm not sure exactly how should I account for the force of air going against the bob.

What I think should be used here is the conservation of mechanical energy:

$E_u=E_k$

$mgh=\frac{1}{2}mv^2$

When the ball passes through the lowest point will be:

$T-mg=\frac{mv^2}{R}$

$T=\frac{mv^2}{R}+mg$

From the first equation:

$mgh=\frac{1}{2}mv^2$

$2g(1-\sin 53^{\circ})=\frac{v^2}{R}$

Therefore the tension will be:

$T=mg+\frac{mv^2}{R}=mg+2mg(1-\sin 53^{\circ})$

Therefore:

$T=2\times 10 + 2 \times 10 (1-\frac{4}{5})= 20 +20(\frac{1}{5})=24\,N.$ But this is not within the alternatives, needless to say that this doesn't seem to be the right answer. Can someone help here please?. I'm still stuck here.

Comment: Hint: the constant force from the wind and the constant downward $g$ together make an effective gravity with a certain magnitude and direction, so that (1) the wire makes an initial angle different from $53$ degrees (2) the lowest point in terms of our usual gravity is not the lowest point in the effective gravity field.
Now solve this new effective problem with the same approach you tried.

Answer (score 1):

Equations:

$l$: length of wire

1) $\Delta E_{pot}=l(1-\cos 53)mg$

2)$ \Delta E_{pot}=(1/2)mv^2+4l \sin 53$

3) $T-mg=mv^2/l$

Comment: Why is the constant force exerted by the air flow completely ignored?

Comment: Lee.The energy "lost" to the system is $4l \sin 53$, i.e. working against the constant force $4N$ for a  distance of  $l \sin 53$ meter, equation 2).Your thoughts?

Comment: oh I see. I thought the $4l$ was for something else. Thanks.

Comment: Lee. It is the 4 N wind force. 1) Is the difference between start and lowest passage potential energy.2) The total energy is used to overcome the wind, and what is left is in the term (1/2)mv^2. 3) Is force balance at the lowest point. OK? I hope the equations are OK.

Comment: @PeterSzilas Can you add a FBD for the justification of these equations?. I get the part of the conservation of mechanical energy. I assume that is at the top and the other at the bottom. And $l$ is just a variable, in my attempt I used the radius. But I'm still stuck at where does $4l\sin 53^{\circ}$ comes from?. Can you explain this please?.

Comment: @PeterSzilas I think this is due the air resistance which it is exactly the source of my confusion. **How** should I translate that into a mathematical expression and **why**?. Can you help me with that part please?.

Comment: Chris.1) $\Delta E_{pot}$ is the energy available due to loss of height. 2) This energy is used to overcome the wind $4N$ for a distance $l\sin 53$, force ×distance =energy spent, remains less energy $(1/2)mv^2$.OK?If you have 50€ in your wallet, and,say, 30€ (working against the wind) are spent, then only 20€ are left (for kinetic energy).3) At lowest point $T-mg=mv^2/l$. If unclear write again!

Comment: Chris.Work against the wind is done  in horizontal direction. $4N$×horizontal distance covered $4×l\sin 53$.This is supplied by $\Delta E_{pot}$, so less remains for $(1/2)mv^2$.

Comment: @PeterSzilas Thanks for that clarification but why did you used the length of the wire and not the tension? Given this situation would it be the same to use tension and not length? Can it be established that $l\cos 53^{\circ}=mg$?.

Comment: @PeterSzilas I did the calculations as directed and Im getting $29.6\,N$ as the tension on the wire. But as I mentioned in my previous comment I am not yet sure why it was used the length and not the tension.

Comment: Chris.I assume you refer to $4 l \sin 53$. Force =4N, horizontal, times distance $l\sin53$, horizontal=$4l\sin 53$. You need the horizontal displacement from the original position. Draw a triangle: A: point of suspension, B: the hand in the picture, draw a perpendicular from B to the dashed line(extended) in the picture, call the perpendicular intersection C, BCA this is a right triangle.You need side length BC, which is $l\sin 53$. Was this your question? If not ask again:)

Answer (score 0):

Because of the peculiar definition of “air resistance” in this problem, namely the fact that the force of “air resistance” is independent of the velocity of the sphere, you have two choices how to handle it.

One way is to treat the “air resistance” like the air resistance in most other problems, and say that work the sphere does against the air resistance represents the transfer of the sphere’s mechanical energy into other energy.

In that interpretation, the mechanical energy of the sphere is not conserved. To see how much mechanical energy is lost between the starting position and the lowest point in the sphere’s path, compute the work done against a $-4$ N horizontal force along that part of the path. The mechanical energy is reduced by that amount.

Another way is to say that no matter where the sphere is or what it is doing, it always is subjected to a force in a direction downward and to the left, and that this force has components $-4$ in the $x$ direction and $-20$ in the $y$ direction. This is a conservative force, and you can plot lines of equal potential energy in the force field. But since the force is not straight down, these lines of equal potential are not horizontal.

According to this interpretation, the mechanical energy of the sphere is conserved, but the potential is **not** $mgy$. Instead, it’s a function of both $x$ and $y$.

Comment: Maybe am I asking too much. But can you add an equation from where to guide myself to get to the answer?. I'm still confused. Initially the air resistance is not acting in the bob because a hand is holding the bob, but when it is released it acts on the bob. But I don't know exactly how to account this effect when the bob goes over to the bottom of the path. Therefore I require some help with a mathematical translation of this part.